# Sense of symbols in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, symbols

What is the sense of symbols in TypeScript? Coming from Java it seems a bit redundant to use together with an interface declaration. Why do I have to set symbols in TypeScript? i.e. following code segment:

```
export const RawProcessOptions = Symbol("RawProcessOptions");
export interface RawProcessOptions extends ProcessOptions {
}
```

Comment: maybe this can help you > https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html

Comment: @pro.mean So a symbol is some other way to declare variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what leads you to believe you have to follow that particular coding pattern; if you have a question about a specific scenario that led to that pattern, please update the question.  In general, a symbol is just a different kind of key you can use to attach a property to an object if you don't want to use a string name (e.g., if you want to be certain of avoiding conflicts with string-named properties).  [This article](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/) has a decent overview.  Symbols are a JavaScript feature not specific to TypeScript (although they find some additional uses in TypeScript for type definition hackery).  TypeScript provides type checking for symbol-named properties just like string-named properties.

Comment: Thanks Matt. The reason for my question is just confusion with the way some things are done in TypeScript. I come from the Java world, where many things are done differently. TypeScript, although an interesting approach, has a harder learning curve than often prognosticated. Hope that helps explaining the -why-.