# Why and when to use Symbol datatype in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, web-frontend

I am learning typescript from past few days and came across a data type called Symbol. But I really did not understand the applications of it.

When I can assign a string to a variable like below:

```
let str="mystring";
```

Why should I use -

```
 let str=Symbol("mystring");
```

What is the advantage of using Symbol in typescript? What is the need of this data type and when to use it? Can someone explain please.

Comment: The docs look pretty self explanatory to me https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sense of symbols in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945296/sense-of-symbols-in-typescript)

Comment: yes I went through this document but they only guide about how to use it. But my question is when to use it.